# Что необходимо учитывать при использовании бесплатного контента?

Tags: лицензирование

Предположим, я использую бесплатную фотографию или шрифт. Как избежать правонарушения в случае, когда у меня есть лицензия на контент и когда её нет?

Также, если не ошибаюсь, сбор пожертвований не является коммерцией? Или это уже «commercial use»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо смотреть под какой лицензией распространяется контент и использовать его в соответствии с установленными лицензией правилами.

Что касается шрифтов, то есть множество отличных вариантов под свободной лицензией (https://fonts.google.com/).

По поводу изображений - надо смотреть каждый конкретный случай. При использовании фотографии из поиска с неопределенной лицензией/автором всегда есть риск нарваться на нарушение авторских прав.

Comment: Хорошо, а что делать с файлами лицензии? Необходимо ли её как-то прикреплять к проекту?

Comment: @Андрей это надо смотреть от лицензии. там должно быть прописано, если нет, но действуйте на свое усмотрение. что касается использования чужого кода, то по best practices лучше выводить информацию об авторе.

Comment: Есть сайты, которые предоставляют бесплатные изображения, но при этом без файла лицензии - на сайте просто указывается её тип (например, [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com)). Как в таком случае поступать?

Comment: @Андрей смотрите по типу лицензии что там написано. обычно если изображение свободное, то никто особо не будет упорствовать в упоминании авторства (но в "лучших практиках" все же рекомендуется это делать)

Comment: @Андрей но это более теоретические выкладки, на практике, особенно в крупных проектах и особенно там, где user generated content бывает сложно соблюсти все условия. если затеваете что-то крупное - смиритесь, будут приставать и на пустом месте. издержки highload так сказать)))

Comment: @Дмитрий, выводить информацию как именно? Указать автора в разделе «Credits»?

Comment: @Андрей обычно их выводят в разделах с правовой информацией. но опять же, нет 100% способа гарантировать себя от претензий третьих лиц. разумно снизить риски и понимать как действовать в той или иной ситуации.

Comment: @Дмитрий, придраться можно всегда :) Пусть хотя бы в Open source можно было использовать. Или даже у создателей открытого ПО в таком случае могут быть проблемы? Хотя, всё зависит от лицензии, опять-таки.

Comment: @Андрей это уже от людей зависит)) надо понимать мотивацию человека, ничего просто так не происходит. из общих правил скажу следующее - пока вы летаете ниже радара особых претензий не будет (даже если и найдут какое изображение - попросят просто удалить), а при появлении значительных финансов появятся и толпы желающих поживиться за ваш счет. а повод можно найти всегда.

Comment: @Дмитрий, немного дополнил вопрос в плане благотворительности. Это является коммерцией?

Comment: @Андрей скорее это некоммерческая деятельность, но лучше проконсультируйтесь с юристами.

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо!